# How to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run instance while also using Serverless-VPC-Connector?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I'm running a cloud run service with a working Cloud-SQL connection using the proxy to connect to the Cloud-SQL instance. The Cloud-SQL instance does not have a private IP configured.

Now there is a new requirement that this service needs to connect to a DB outside of GCP, for which it needs a static egress-IP that can be whitelisted. I attempted to achieve this via a serverless-VPC-connector (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip).

**Problem:** When I add the VPC-connector to the service, and configure it to route all traffic through the vpc-connector, the service fails to deploy because it cannot connect to Cloud-SQL via the proxy anymore:

`CloudSQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: Post "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<>/instances/<>/createEphemeral?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": context deadline exceeded`

I was able to get this exact setup to work for a cloud function (identical external DB, CloudSQL, and vpc connector), and I'm at a loss as to why this wouldn't work for Cloud Run, and I'm wondering if there is additional configuration required which I'm missing?

Is it possible to connect to Cloud-SQL with the proxy, while at the same time using a VPC-connector to achieve a static egress IP?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a static egress public IP, you only did the half of the path. Now, you need to add a [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview), that gets the VPC connector range and NAT the traffic to the internet. In this NAT,  you can define a public static IP which will be used for all outgoing communications.

In any cases, if you want to reach Cloud SQL, it's better to use Cloud SQL proxy because the connection is secured (encrypted channel). If you use directly the public IP, add a [SSL certificat](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance) to encrypt the communication over the public internet. (same thing if your instance is located outside GCP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a CLoud NAT with a cloud router, I followed this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip. I will update the question to make this more explicit.

And I would like to use the Cloud SQL proxy, however that is what stops working once I add the vpc connector for some reason.

Comment: Humm, ok. When you add your Serverless VPC connector and route all traffic, the Cloud SQL proxy fail, correct?

Comment: Yes. And when I remove the VPC connector again, it works again.

Comment: I tested and yes, there is a case where it doesn't work: when VPC Connector is set with VPC egress to all. I reported this issue to Google. I will keep you posted (if I can share the answer)

Comment: Hi Guillaume, do you know of any news on this issue? Thanks

Comment: No, only that an internal bug has been open. And because it's internal to Google, and I'm not a Googler, I don't know!

Comment: I understand, thank you. Guess I keep my eyes on the release notes: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes